# How to show a polyline on Google map using JSON array of latitude and JSON array of longitude?

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I'm making an app that needs to show a line on Google map. Coordinates for the polyline are in separate JSON arrays – one array for latitude and one for longitude. My question is how do I get the data from JSON url and to show the polyline on map?
Here is my JSON structure:

```
{“1”: { “id”:”1”,"lat_list":[43.193850940837,43.193553712737,43.193225195784,43.193131333473,43.193146977202],"lng_list":[23.284599781036,23.28423500061,23.28382730484,23.283634185791,23.283518850803]}}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: if you control the source data I'd suggest a better data structure would help

Comment: @RamRaider Thank you for your response! Please would you be so kind to give me an example of better data structure?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps, and you should notice to replace `”` and `“` with `"`. You can also take a look at [google map polyline and polygon tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/polygon-tutorial) for more details about google map polygons.

```
try {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("{\"1\": { \"id\":\"1\",\"lat_list\":[43.193850940837,43.193553712737,43.193225195784,43.193131333473,43.193146977202],\"lng_list\":[23.284599781036,23.28423500061,23.28382730484,23.283634185791,23.283518850803]}}");
    JSONObject obj2 = obj.getJSONObject("1");
    JSONArray lat_list = obj2.getJSONArray("lat_list");
    JSONArray lng_list = obj2.getJSONArray("lng_list");

    PolylineOptions polyLineOptions = new PolylineOptions()
            .clickable(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < lat_list.length() && i < lng_list.length(); i++) {
        double lat = lat_list.getDouble(i);
        double lng = lng_list.getDouble(i);
        polyLineOptions.add(lat, lng);

    }
    googleMap.addPolyline(polyLineOptions);


} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```